# Как в C++ подключить Imgui к GTA SAMP sampfuncs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, плагин, документация, imgui

Есть ли документация как подключить ImgUi к C++ для работы на сервере SAMP. Пытался делать сам, вылезает ошибка приложение не является Win32, использовал imgui-directx-9-kiero-hook, как готовый проект, пробовал все Release, Debug, x64, x86.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.